# python flask extends base template does not work

Tags: python, html, templates, flask, web-applications

I'm trying to use templates for my flask app, but for some reasons the templates do not work even though I directed the paths and included {% block content %}{% endblock content %} in both the template files. I am confused as of why this wouldn't work. What is wrong here?

/template/base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Class Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body class="background-color">
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <a href="/">Display All Songs</a>
        <a href="/add-songs">Add Songs</a>
        <a href="/delete-songs">Delete Songs</a>
        <a href="/search-songs">Search Songs</a>
      </nav>
      <main>{% block content %}{% endblock content %}</main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

/template/home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    {% for song in song_list%}
    <div>
      <p>Music Name: {{song["song_name"]}}</h1>
      <p>user: {{song["user_name"]}}</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    {% endfor %}
```

app.py

```
import pymongo
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)


# Views
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/<user_name>")

def index():
    return render_template("home.html")

def display_songs(user_name=None):
    song_list = None
    if user_name:
        song_list = list(db.songs.find({"user_name": user_name}))
    else:
        song_list = list(db.songs.find({}))

    return render_template('home.html', song_list=song_list)


@app.route("/add-songs")
def add_songs():
    return render_template("addSongs.html")


@app.route("/delete-songs")
def delete_songs():
    return render_template("deleteSongs.html")


@app.route("/search-songs")
def search_songs():
    return render_template("searchSongs.html")


# Form methods
@app.route("/api/add-songs", methods=["POST"])
def addSongs():
    user_name = request.form["user_name"]
    song_name = request.form["song_name"]
    db.songs.insert_one({"user_name": user_name, "song_name": song_name})
    return redirect("/")


@app.route("/api/delete-songs", methods=["POST"])
def deleteSongs():
    user_name = request.form["user_name"]
    song_name = request.form["song_name"]
    db.songs.delete_one({"user_name": user_name, "song_name": song_name})
    return redirect("/")


@app.route("/api/search-songs", methods=["POST"])
def searchSongs():
    user_name = request.form["user_name"]
    return redirect("/" + user_name)


# Connecting to local host
connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
db = connection["test_database"]
```

Answer (score 3):

The `{% block content %}{% endblock content %}` in your home.html template is meant to be enclosing the html code that will be injected in the `{% block content %}{% endblock content %}` string of your base.html. You need to move the closing tag `{% endblock content %}` at the end of your template.

`home.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% for song in song_list%}
    <div>
      <p>Music Name: {{song["song_name"]}}</h1>
      <p>user: {{song["user_name"]}}</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```